# Setting up User-Agent blocking in .htaccess or my site is being attacked

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent, blocking, agent

My site is being attacked.
What I've done:
In the .htaccess file, about 4200 IP-addresses are blocked, with which requests were sent in batches in this way:
allow from all
deny from 200.6.169.250
deny from 85.109.127.48

All requests come from a single user agent.

How to block the user agent correctly
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.284?

Yes, at the moment I wrote this and I do not know if there is a correct option here?

```
# Blocking user agents:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.284" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla/5\.0 (Windows NT 10\.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537\.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85\.0\.4183\.121 Safari/537\.36" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 10\.0; Win64; x64\) AppleWebKit\/537\.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Chrome\/85\.0\.4183\.121 Safari\/537\.36$"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: _“and I do not know if there is a correct option here?”_ - what do you mean, you are not sure whether this works as intended or not? Well then test it - tools/extensions to modify your own browser’s user agent are available en masse …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing this same attack. Blocking that browser string (as opposed to the IP's, which are all over the place) seems like the best call. I tend to suspect a browser or some exploit as a potential cause, given the pace of the attack, IP variability, and network speed differences. Unless it is a bot network that is attacking many places at once?

Note that we've seen what looks to be legitimate traffic from the longer versions of the browser string: i.e. additional info in the agent string beyond the `Safari/537.36` appear legitimate, while only those that end at that exact point appear to be definite bots of some sort - at least, at this time.

If you'd like to block all the variations, the following works:

```
# Blocking user agents:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "^Mozilla/5\.0 \(Windows NT 10\.0; Win64; x64\) AppleWebKit/537\.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Chrome/85\.0\.4183\.121 Safari/537\.36.*$"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Escaping the parenthesis is required (as you did in your last condition) since the RewriteCond expects regular expressions by default. While the dots would have been fine, I preferred being explicit. (For whatever reason, Apache doesn't care that /'s are not escaped - their documentation even includes examples like this too.)

Note that you don't have to use Regex if you want to block just one specific string, by using `=` as follows. No escaping needed in this case, but the quotes are:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
```

I recommend doing testing with something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/ Other common tools (e.g. curl) are great for it too: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/curl-set-user-agent-command-linux-unix/

Comment: As another note: depending on how you've done it, the 4200 blocked IP's is an unfortunate cost of every request your system is handling. It would probably be best to block those by iptables. If you want to keep the block in the hands of Apache, a rewrite_map using a compiled lookup table would also save some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Blocking user agents:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 OPR/71.0.3770.284" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 10\.0\; Win64\; x64\) AppleWebKit\/537\.36 \(KHTML\, like Gecko\) Chrome\/85\.0\.4183\.121 Safari\/537\.36 OPR\/71\.0\.3770\.284" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 10\.0\; Win64\; x64\) AppleWebKit\/537\.36 \(KHTML\, like Gecko\) Chrome\/85\.0\.4183\.121 Safari\/537\.36\ (.*)$"
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

The first and second locks are the same, while the third allows you to change the line endings. You can leave only one to choose from. It depends on what is required.